# lapply misses a variable name when used with lm and wanting to reduce iteration?

Tags: r, lapply, lm

I have used `melt` to combine all my 32 columns into a single column, their values into a single column, and the independent variable into a single column.

I then wanted to use `lapply` to generate a `lm` matching the rows of
`Years   Species   Farmland`

There were two ways of me wanting to do this;
1. To take the `lm` of one variable name i.e. Starling values across all years (1994:2013)
2. To take the `lm` of all variables names I.e. Starling, Skylark, Lapwing .... Farmland values together across each year.

An example of my data:

```
structure(list(Years = c(1994L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L
), Species = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Starling", "Skylark", 
"YellowWagtail", "Kestrel", "Yellowhammer", "Greenfinch"), class = "factor"), 
    Farmland = c(13260L, 13520L, 8129L, 15575L, 18686L, 18541L
    )), row.names = c(1L, 20L, 40L, 60L, 80L, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

A further example:

```
'data.frame':   570 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Years   : int  1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2002 2003 2004 ...
 $ Species : Factor w/ 30 levels "Starling","Skylark",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Farmland: int  13260 15551 16335 18997 18571 18376 15770 16054 15101 16276 ...
```

Code for `lm` for Q.1:

```
df_try <- lapply(1:n, function(x) lm(Farmland ~ Years + Species, work_practice))
```

The output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Farmland ~ Years + Species, data = work_practice)

Coefficients:
         (Intercept)                 Years        SpeciesSkylark  
           -708278.6                 363.0                 578.8  
SpeciesYellowWagtail        SpeciesKestrel   SpeciesYellowhammer  
             -9329.8                -744.4                -238.7  
   SpeciesGreenfinch        SpeciesSwallow    SpeciesHousemartin  
               246.3                 506.6               -3928.5  
       SpeciesLinnet  SpeciesGreyPartridge     SpeciesTurtleDove  
              -680.2               -5825.1               -5417.4  
  SpeciesCornbunting      SpeciesBullfinch     SpeciesSongthrush  
            -12187.9               -5688.7                -279.1  
    SpeciesBlackbird        SpeciesDunnock    SpeciesWhitethroat  
               490.2                 299.0                 231.6  
         SpeciesRook    SpeciesReedBunting      SpeciesStockdove  
              -653.9               -6864.5               -1788.0  
    SpeciesGoldfinch        SpeciesJackdaw           SpeciesWren  
               156.6                -637.3                 553.1  
        SpeciesRobin        SpeciesBluetit       SpeciesGreatTit  
               328.7                 460.3                 384.3  
SpeciesLongtailedTit      SpeciesChaffinch        SpeciesBuzzard  
             -1359.8                 499.7               -6888.2  
  SpeciesSparrowhawk  
             -4458.5
```

The problem with this; Starling is missing (The first variable name), and Years is not necessary for the result (How can this be removed) this is iterated on call 19 times which I assume is because of the dataframe. Is there a way to call this only once?

I have tried doing this when the variable (Species) was in columns but the output only calls for one variable 19 times...

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that if `r` had to estimate the model with all the regressors in `Species`, then we would reach perfect colinearity. I will use `data.table::dcast` to transform `Species` into dummies:

```
df <- structure(list(Years = c(1994L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L
), Species = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Starling", "Skylark", 
                                       "YellowWagtail", "Kestrel", "Yellowhammer", "Greenfinch"), class = "factor"), 
Farmland = c(13260L, 13520L, 8129L, 15575L, 18686L, 18541L
)), row.names = c(1L, 20L, 40L, 60L, 80L, 100L), class = "data.frame") 

dfDummies <- suppressWarnings(data.table::dcast(df, Years + Farmland ~ Species, fun.aggregate=function(x) 1, fill=0))
```

On console:

```
> dfDummies
  Years Farmland Starling Skylark YellowWagtail Kestrel Yellowhammer Greenfinch
1  1994    13260        1       0             0       0            0          0
2  1994    13520        0       1             0       0            0          0
3  1995     8129        0       0             1       0            0          0
4  1996    15575        0       0             0       1            0          0
5  1997    18686        0       0             0       0            1          0
6  1998    18541        0       0             0       0            0          1
```

Note how the dummies are mutually exclusive:

```
> rowSums(dfDummies[, as.character(df[["Species"]])])
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

This means that the intercept can be written as a linear combination of the `Species` binary variables. `R` knows this and it silently removes one of the columns from the estimation --perfect colinearity makes impossible to find a unique solution to the OLS problem.

More on perfect colinearity [here](https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/6-4-ols-assumptions-in-multiple-regression.html).

I am not sure why you are using `lapply()` here. If you have only a single `data.frame` and you are interested in estimating a particular model with all observations, then you can just run:

```
lm(formula = Farmland ~ Years + Species, df)
```